# What event that is generated by clicking once on an item in a list

Tags: java, awt

Which event is generated when clicking once on an item in a list in **java**
I found something like

> selection event for double clicking.

But nothing for single click that selects an item.

Comment: With which representation ? I mean how do you see the list to be able to click on it ?

Comment: The list is static, there isn't any further extension to the items on the list.

Comment: Which framework are you using to show the list? Swing, Android, JavaFX, AWT, QT, SWT? In other words, please clearly describe your question and add some working code if you want an answer.

Comment: It's my first time, so I might miss out on a point or two, please excuse it.

Comment: The list is AWT framework.

Comment: Tried to clarfy the question

Comment: Can you post a code of the list and explain what exactly you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with an Item from a JList which is selected, you can try to use

```
   list.getSelectedIndex()
```

And use an ActionListener with a button to do whatever else you need. Without a peace of code from you and information what exactly you want, I cannot come up with better Idea, sorry.

Else,
You can use MouseEvent and with

```
 MouseClicked(){}
```

Method and If statement,

```
  if (List.getSelectedIndex() == ...)
```

To Perform Action.